# How to make a "ImageView" field as mandatory in android?

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I have a imageview field in my android app, onclick of the same I have given a "open camera" functionality and the user can click the photo from camera and it gets uploaded to ImageView

```
  b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(user_image.getDrawable() == null ){

                Toast.makeText(NewCall4.this, "No image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{

                Intent i=new Intent(NewCall4.this,NewCall5.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    }
    );
```

What I want is, if I am not uploading the image in the imageview then it should give the error/toast message as "Image not uploaded"

Comment: You will get uri after open camera and choose image,You cant check uri is null or not before uploading image.

Comment: Appreciate your answer kabir.. Yes I am getting URI and choose image on imageview click.. What I want is if image is not uploaded then on button click it should not go to next page instead should give error/toast message as "please upload image"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can check the Drawable if attached to ImageView

```
Imageview imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
if(imageView.getDrawable() == null){
 //Then Nothing is attached with imageviw
}
```

Comment: hi chandan.thanks for the solution you provided..but still i am not able to achieve the desired output..i tried your solution and inserted on button click so that if imageview is null it should show toast message else redirect to next activity..i am still getting redirected to next page even if image is not uploaded

Comment: worked like a pro now..i get to know after long time that,i need to change my "app:src" to "android:background" in xml file..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- It is so simple. When You call Intent for camera open it gives callback in onActivityResult in that just pass the value of the image. And check it is null or not in the click event.

> **Example :-**

=> **To Open Camera** :-

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent1, camera);
```

- You will get a callback in onActivityResult

=> **onActivityResult :-** ( I am getting actual Image path here)

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == camera) {
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    addprofile.setImageBitmap(photo); // set image to imageview
    Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
    File finalfile = new File(getrealpathfromuri(tempUri));
    imagepath = finalfile.toString(); // imagepath is a global variable
}

private Uri getImageUri(Context applicationContext, Bitmap photo) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(applicationContext.getContentResolver(),photo,"Title",null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

private String getrealpathfromuri(Uri tempUri) {
    String path = "";
    if(getContentResolver() != null){
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(tempUri, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idk = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            path = cursor.getString(idk);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

- Finally imagepath has an actual path of the image.

=> **Check imagepath null or not** :- (in event)

```
if (imagepath == null) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select FileImage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try something like this

```
 Imageview img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image){

    img .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, id);
                }
    });
```

And OnResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get(“data”);
img.setImageBitmap(photo);
 }
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer kiran.. I have already done this.. But my issue is I have a button named "next".. So what I want is if I am not uploading an image then on that button click it should give error/toast message as "Image not uploaded"

Comment: you can try like if(img.getDrawable() == null) { Toast.makeText(context,"Image not attached,Toast.Short).show();}

Comment: you can just pass any value to the global variable and just check it is null or not.if it is null then make Toast and if it has value then go further.

Comment: hi..thanks for solution kiran and bhaven..but still m getting redirected to next page on button click even if image is not uploaded..for the reference i have provided my code in my question